# Xdebug: How to disable 'xdebug.halt_level'

Tags: php, xdebug

After installing Xdebug and trying debugging some code with netbeans I get masked error like in this [example](https://akrabat.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/2015-xdebug.png) and I don't like it. I'd like to get rid of the mask Xdebug uses to show errors.

I know it has something to do with 'xdebug.halt_level'

but I don't know how to get rid of this mask.

Comment: Hi, if the community is to help you, you really need to include your relevant code so that people can replicate the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I don't want to get rid of the error, I want to get rid of the mask Xdebug uses to show errors

Comment: Ah, ok. The code might still help though, so that people can replicate the problem.

Comment: No. I googled and found that image. I used as an example for the mask.

Comment: In your `php.ini` maybe try setting `xdebug.halt_level = 0`

Comment: It's not working, phpinfo() shows 'xdebug.halt_level' default value is 0

Comment: Was it already set to that value, and did you restart apache?

Comment: Yes, it was set before and yes I restarted apache

Comment: Okay, then maybe try using the value of `-1` or `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Codelobster to debug my PHP code instead of XDebug, it was the easiest solution for me.